# JSONEncoder subclassing went wrong

Tags: python, json, regex, python-3.x

I need some help regarding extending standard `json.JSONEncoder` in Python.

I have object like:

```
temp = {
    "a": "test/string",
    "b": {
        "b1": "one/more/string",
        "b2": 666
    },
    "c": 123
}
```

I need to override(extend) encoding of str to replace `/` to `\/`.

Standard json.dumps will return:

```
{"a":"test/string","b":{"b1":"one/more/string","b2":666},"c":123}
```

And i need to get:

```
{"a":"test\\/string","b":{"b1":"one\\/more\\/string","b2":666},"c":123}
```

Don't even try to ask me why i need to do so... I have overwritten `default()` method already but it gets ignored when i calling `json.dumps` with my subclass

My encoder class:

```
class RetardJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, str):
            return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj.replace("/", "\/"))

        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

Comment: Please, share your code what do you have right now. It would be easier to find a mistake.

Comment: I updated my question with code. Calling it with `json.dumps(obj, cls=RetardJSONEncoder)`

Comment: str objects are always encoded internally and you have no option to override it.

Comment: I'd suggest you to fix this on a reader side where you really need it. Otherwise, you'll end up with your own JSON library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With current implementation of `json` package, it's impossible to re-define how strings are encoded. You'd prefer to apply a fix for your client side or encode strings before you put them in the object to send. Otherwise, you'll end up with your own JSON library.